# I can't get my CRON email settings to work

Tags: unix, cron, macos-high-sierra

Just like the title says, the jobs all run on time but the console will not send me the logs to my gmail account. I pasted an example below.v OS is MAC OS High Sierra  Thanks!

```
MAILTO='email@gmail.com'
* * * * * usr/bin/python PathTOScript
```

Comment: Do you really have `usr/bin/python` and not `/usr/bin/python`? In any case, we have no idea what your script does. If you're trying to capture its output, see what happens with `echo hello`.

Comment: Does your MacOS actually have a mailer installed and configured? Can you send emails from the command-line?

Comment: @mivk I just did a test and it doesn't look like I can.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su] or [apple.se]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.